# what keeps overwriting my bootstrap/cache in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, amazon-dynamodb

The [instructions](https://github.com/baopham/laravel-dynamodb) for installing a query builder for dynamodb in Laravel which include the step

"Update DynamoDb config in config/dynamodb.php"

Obviously then I put in the required credentials.

I then create a test model and that's fine but periodically,
Keeps on stripping the values back to:

```
 'dynamodb' => 
  array (
   'default' => 'aws',
   'connections' => 
   array (
     'aws' => 
     array (
       'credentials' => 
         array (
         'key' => NULL,
         'secret' => NULL,
         'token' => NULL,
       ),
    'region' => NULL,
    'debug' => NULL,
  ),
```

I tried also putting the values in my .env file as such:

```
DYNAMODB_KEY=
DYNAMODB_SECRET=
DYNAMODB_REGION=
```

But these are not read.
Is there a step somewhere I have missed?

Comment: Why on Earth would you come cry for help on SO? Just ask on the repository itself https://github.com/baopham/laravel-dynamodb/issues

Comment: Its not 'crying' as you so patronisingly put it. it's a framework/integration issue that is likely something seen by others on SO that have more experience than me. SO folk are often super responsive and often the first port of call when searching for answers on the web.

Comment: In future your first port should be package repository itself, its happening only to one of the configs right? There must be something wrong with service provider (of the package), or you have the file in `.gitignore` or some weird case that happens only to you, because of your machine. I checked the service provider and it looks OK to me. Have you ran `php artisan config:cache` command by a chance?

Comment: Thanks I will take your advice and post one there in a moment. php artisan config:cache clears the settings in bootstrap/cache/config.php. As per the instructions I set the key, secret and region details but I don't know how/what mechanisim is used to transfer them to bootstrap/cache/config. If I do it manually the code runs. if I run php artisan config:cache they are erased....